# Python, lil_matrix : set the diagonal to be a power of a number

Tags: python, matrix

I want the entries of the diagonal of a matrix A to be the power of a real number `c>1` such that `a_ii=c^(i+1)`, i.e. from a smaller to bigger power as we go through the diagonal.

My matrix is a 10x10 square matrix.

```
from scipy.sparse import lil_matrix
A = lil_matrix((10, 10))
```

I thought about using the function `A.setdiag` but I can't figure out how to introduce the dependency on the `i`.

Comment: note that ``x^y`` in Python is a binary XOR, not an exponentiation. Exponentiation is ``x ** y``.

Comment: Sure, I got mixed up ! Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `A.setdiag`:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse as sparse
N = 5
c = 1.1
A = sparse.lil_matrix((N, N))
A.setdiag(c**np.arange(1, N+1))
print(A.todense())
```

yields

```
[[ 1.1      0.       0.       0.       0.     ]
 [ 0.       1.21     0.       0.       0.     ]
 [ 0.       0.       1.331    0.       0.     ]
 [ 0.       0.       0.       1.4641   0.     ]
 [ 0.       0.       0.       0.       1.61051]]
```

---

NumPy performs elementwise arithmetic on arrays. So raising a scalar, `c`, to an array, `np.arange(1, N+1)`, returns a new NumPy array with values `c**i` for each `i` in `np.arange(1, N+1)`:

```
In [18]: c, N = 1.1, 5

In [21]: np.arange(1, N+1)
Out[21]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

In [22]: c**np.arange(1, N+1)
Out[22]: array([ 1.1    ,  1.21   ,  1.331  ,  1.4641 ,  1.61051])
```

Comment: Perfect thanks ! I had to edit and use `A.setdiag(c**(numpy.arange(10)+1))`
 but that's exactly what I needed.

Comment: I used ` c**np.arange(1, N+1)` , thanks for the edit !